# rspec fails where 'current_user' code written in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have started rspec coding recently and i am new to rails framework, rspec fails where i am using 'current_user' in controller. Please check below for my controller and rspec code. Thanks in advance.

Controller code:

```
def task
  @tasks = current_user.alerts.where(kind: "TASK")
end
```

rspec code:

```
describe "get #task" do
  it "assigns a task" do            
    sign_in(@user)
    get :task       
    expect(response).to have_http_status(200)       
  end
```

Comment: Are you defining a sign_in method in some place, or you are using it for devise? , if sign_in is a method could you please show it?

Comment: sign_in using for devise. (Used devise gem file)

Comment: I will post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
 user = FactoryGirl.create(:user) # Don't forget to create a factory for user
 user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
 sign_in user
```

It is better to put it in support/devise.rb:

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

you can say login_user instead of sign_in(@user)

Comment: Thanks a lot Hany Elsioufy,first one worked for me,2nd one i tried but that code couldn't help me,i got log_in undefined method error,once again i will check it,thanks